# Prove a set to be an open set

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be a continuous function ,and let $U=\left\{(x,y):y>f(x)\right\}$ Prove that U is an open set in $R^{2}$.

The result is intuitively obvious.My thought is following: for any point $x=(x_{0},y_{0})$ in $U$, there is a positive number $r$ such that $r=\min\left\{d((x_{0},y_{0}),(x,f(x))\mid x\in R\right\}$,so we can find an open ball contained in $U$. But I don't know how to prove it .

Comment: There's an unmatched parenthesis in your expression for $r$. Also note that you can get the right font using `\min` and the right spacing using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ via $F((x,y)) = y-f(x)$. This is a continous function and the set you are looking for is $f^{-1}((0,\infty)$. SInce it is the preimage of an open set under a continous function it is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that a set is open if and only if its complement is closed. Consider any sequence in $U^c$ (the complement of $U$). That is consider any convergent sequence of points $(x_n,y_n)$ such that $y_n\leq f(x_n)$ for all $n$. Denote the limit of this sequence by $(x,y)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$. By a theorem about limits, since $y_n\leq f(x_n)$ it must be that $y\leq f(x)$ and so $(x,y)$ is also in $U^c$ and therefore $U^c$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is correct. Let $x=(x_0, y_0) \in U$. Let $r=\inf\{d(x,(y,f(y)) | y \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Firstly, $r>0$, because if $r=0$, then there is a sequence $(x_n, f(x_n))$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n, f(x_n)) = (x_0, y_0)$, so by continuity of $f$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x_0) = y_0$, but $y_0 > f(x_0)$, a contradiction.

Secondly, $B(x, r) \subseteq U$. Suppose not. Then there exists at least one $(z,w) \in B(x, r)$ with $f(z) \geq w$. If $f(z)=w$ we are done, because in that case $(z, f(z)) \in B(x, r)$, so $d(x, (z, f(z)) < r$, contradicting the fact $r$ is the $\inf$. If $f(z)>w$ we will find some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $(a, f(a)) \in B(x, r)$ such that by the same argument we arrive at a contradiction. If $x_0 = z$, then because $y_0>f(z)>w$, the point $(z, f(z))$ lies on the line connecting $(z,w)$ and $(x_0, y_0)$, which is contained in $B(x,r)$, and this line must intersect $(z,f(z))$ by the intermediate value theorem. Assume $x_0 <z$, the case $x_0>z$ is dealt with similarly. Now let $\tau : [x_0, z] \rightarrow [w, y_0]$ be the linear function with $\tau(x_0)=y_0$ and $\tau(z) = w$. Then the graph of $\tau$ lies entirely in $B(x, r)$ and $f(z)-\tau(z)>0$, while $f(x_0) -\tau(x_0) < 0 $. So by the intermediate value theorem there is some $\alpha \in [x_0, z]$ with $f(\alpha)=\tau(\alpha)$, so $(\alpha, \tau(\alpha))=(\alpha, f(\alpha))$ is on the line connecting $(x_0, y_0)$ and $(z, w)$ (and thus in $B(x, r)$).

Tips for understanding the proof:

1) Draw a picture of the situation.

2) Try proving some of the unproven facts in the proof(the things about 'lines'), which I ommited because I did not want to write down explicit parametrisations. Let me know if you have any trouble with that.